# Past perfect progressive/continuous tense in the passive voice

Tags: tenses, past-tense, passive-voice

Here's the hypothetical situation ...

Our CEO (Joe) was coming to visit our office from out of town, and he wanted to see a report that we had been preparing for him. At the time of his visit, various organizations had been working on the preparation of the report for a month, and it still wasn't finished. I don't want to say who was working on the report, so I want to refer to the preparation using the passive voice.

So, could I say ...

> At the time of Joe's visit, the report had been being prepared for a month

That sounds very strange, to me.

Obviously I could avoid the problem by saying

> At the time of Joe's visit, the report had been under preparation for a month

but I'm interested to know if the first version, with the passive voice, is even correct English.

Comment: I know you said you didn't want to say who was working on it, but you said "we" had been preparing it, implying that it was an office-wide effort. Why can't you say "At the time of Joe's visit, we had been preparing the report for a month."?

Comment: OK. I guess I could change the "we" to "various organizations". But the real question is whether the passive voice can work in this situation.

Comment: You need to use the definite article "the" before time as it is not a mass noun any more. As @JohnClifford mentioned, what is wrong with using "we" which doesn't indicate who it was. It is as vague as it gets.

Comment: Grammatically speaking, you could say "the report had been being prepared for a month", yes. It does sound strange, but it's not ungrammatical.

Comment: "At **the** time of Joe's visit..."

Comment: It's easy to find alternative ways to say this. I gave one myself. But that's not the question. I'm asking whether the phrasing with the passive voice is grammatically correct.

Comment: John said the sentence has no grammatical issue.

Comment: @Rathony -- Yes. I saw what John wrote. I upvoted. My comment was to discourage other people from suggesting alternatives.

Comment: It's the  *past perfect progressive/continuous tense* in the passive voice. http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastperfectcontinuous.html The PPP is rarely used in the passive, it sounds awkward and can appear confusing

Comment: related: [Future Continuous and Perfect Continuous tenses in Passive Voice](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192481/future-continuous-and-perfect-continuous-tenses-in-passive-voice) and [How to use Present Perfect Continuous in Passive form?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/282335/how-to-use-present-perfect-continuous-in-passive-form)

Comment: @Mari-LouA -- Yep. Duplicate. Thanks. Also, thanks for giving me the correct grammatical jargon. I will change the question title.